# TabBar icon color change animation

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, tabbar

How to apply the same color change animation that's applied to `TabBar` text (label) to the icon at the same time, instead of instant changing the color of the icon?

[image]

This is triggered when swiping, not when tapping on the tab itself.

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that you've tried so far?

Comment: Code is just like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53970085/14004876

Comment: You check about `ColorTween`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted transcribing icons to fonts.

https://www.fluttericon.com/

https://dev.to/techwithsam/how-to-add-your-own-custom-icons-in-your-flutter-application-made-easy-1bnj