# Why doesn't the color change everywhere in the tabbar?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, tabbar

My task is to change the background to orange on click, the text under the icon to orange, and the icon to white. However, I only change the color of the text. Why?

my tabs -

```
return Tab(
      height: 90,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 71,
            height: 71,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                shape: BoxShape.circle
            ),
            child: IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(iconName, size: 26, color: configColors.homeIcon,)),
          ),
          FittedBox(
            child: Text(header, style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Mark-Pro", fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 15),),
          )
        ],
      ),);
```

my tabbar -

```
TabBar(
                       isScrollable: true,
                       labelColor: configColors.orange,
                       unselectedLabelColor: configColors.darkBlue,
                       indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
                       tabs:  const [
                         Tabs('Phones', Icons.phone_iphone),
                         Tabs('Computer', Icons.computer),
                         Tabs('Health', Icons.monitor_heart_outlined),
                         Tabs('Books', Icons.menu_book),
                         Tabs('Watch', Icons.watch_later_outlined),
                       ],
                     ),
```

full code -

```
 return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: configColors.bgHome,
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(17, 50, 33, 0),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 50,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.place_outlined, color: configColors.orange, size: 17,)),
                      Text('Zihuatanejo, Gro', style: TextStyle(
                          color: configColors.darkBlue,
                          fontFamily: "Mark-Pro",
                          fontSize: 15,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                      ),),
                      IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.expand_more, color: configColors.grey, size: 20,))
                    ],
                  ),
                  IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Image.asset('assets/image/vector.png'))
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 18),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text('Select Category', style: TextStyle(
                        color: configColors.darkBlue,
                        fontFamily: "Mark-Pro",
                        fontSize: 25,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700
                    ),),
                    TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('view all', style: TextStyle(
                        color: configColors.orange,
                        fontFamily: "Mark-Pro",
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
                    ),))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child:           DefaultTabController(
                    length: 5, // length of tabs
                    initialIndex: 0,

                    child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: TabBar(
                          isScrollable: true,
                          labelColor: configColors.orange,
                          unselectedLabelColor: configColors.darkBlue,
                          indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
                          tabs:  const [
                            Tabs('Phones', Icons.phone_iphone),
                            Tabs('Computer', Icons.computer),
                            Tabs('Health', Icons.monitor_heart_outlined),
                            Tabs('Books', Icons.menu_book),
                            Tabs('Watch', Icons.watch_later_outlined),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      // Container(
                      //   margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35),
                      //   child: Row(
                      //     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      //     children: [
                      //       TextField(
                      //         decoration: InputDecoration(
                      //           enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      //             borderSide:
                      //             BorderSide(width: 3, color: Colors.greenAccent), //<-- SEE HERE
                      //             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                      //           ),
                      //         ),
                      //       ),
                      //     ],
                      //   ),
                      // ),

                      Container(
                          height: 400, //height of TabBarView
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border(top: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 0.5))
                          ),
                          child: TabBarView(children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text('Display Tab 1', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text('Display Tab 2', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text('Display Tab 3', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text('Display Tab 4', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text('Display Tab 5', style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                              ),
                            )])
                      )
                    ])
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )

      ),
    );
  }
}

class Tabs extends StatelessWidget {
  final String header;
  final IconData iconName;
  const Tabs(this.header, this.iconName);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Tab(
      height: 90,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 71,
            height: 71,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                shape: BoxShape.circle
            ),
            child: IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(iconName, size: 26, color: configColors.homeIcon,)),
          ),
          FittedBox(
            child: Text(header, style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Mark-Pro", fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 15),),
          )
        ],
      ),);
  }
```

[image: tabbar]

Comment: Can you include full widget

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51941328/flutter-change-tabitem-background-when-selected

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I have corrected the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to determine if it was triggered by using the index value at the time of tapping.

[image]

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<bool> _selected = [true, false, false, false];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 4,
        child: TabBar(
          isScrollable: true,
          labelColor: Colors.orange,
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.blueGrey,
          indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
          onTap: (index) => _selectedState(index),
          tabs: [
            Tabs('Phones', Icons.phone_iphone, 0),
            Tabs('Computer', Icons.computer, 1),
            Tabs('Books', Icons.menu_book, 2),
            Tabs('Watch', Icons.watch_later_outlined, 3),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget Tabs(String header, IconData iconName, int index) {
    return Tab(
      height: 90,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 71,
            height: 71,
            decoration:
                BoxDecoration(color: _selected[index] == true ? Colors.orange : Colors.white, shape: BoxShape.circle),
            child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(
                  iconName,
                  size: 26,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                )),
          ),
          FittedBox(
            child: Text(
              header,
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: "Mark-Pro",
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  fontSize: 15),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _selectedState(int index) {
    setState(() {
      switch (index) {
        case 0:
          _selected[0] = true;
          _selected[1] = false;
          _selected[2] = false;
          _selected[3] = false;
          break;
        case 1:
          _selected[0] = false;
          _selected[1] = true;
          _selected[2] = false;
          _selected[3] = false;
          break;
        case 2:
          _selected[0] = false;
          _selected[1] = false;
          _selected[2] = true;
          _selected[3] = false;
          break;
        case 3:
          _selected[0] = false;
          _selected[1] = false;
          _selected[2] = false;
          _selected[3] = true;
          break;
        default:
          _selected[0] = true;
          _selected[1] = false;
          _selected[2] = false;
          _selected[3] = false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but where is _selected defined? (Undefined name '_selected'. (Documentation) Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name)

Comment: sorry, eidt my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try below named parameter by assigning color in Tabbar widget.

```
indicatorColor: Colors.orange,
```

Comment: Thanks to this, the bottom line appears, but I do not need it.

Comment: You need to compare index in Tab widget that you customized. Such as index == currentIndex ? Colors.orange : Colors.white. Also, Don't forget to change the state.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TabController` to track the selected tap, and play with the color decoration by passing active index.

```dart
class FAG extends StatefulWidget {
  FAG({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FAG> createState() => _FAGState();
}

class _FAGState extends State<FAG> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final TabController controller = TabController(length: 5, vsync: this)
    ..addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
      body: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(17, 50, 33, 0),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          child: TabBar(
                            controller: controller,
                            isScrollable: true,
                            labelColor: Colors.orange,
                            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                            indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
                            tabs: [
                              Tabs(
                                'Phones',
                                Icons.phone_iphone,
                                isActive: controller.index == 0,
                              ),
                              Tabs(
                                'Computer',
                                Icons.computer,
                                isActive: controller.index == 1,
                              ),
                              Tabs(
                                'Health',
                                Icons.monitor_heart_outlined,
                                isActive: controller.index == 2,
                              ),
                              Tabs(
                                'Books',
                                Icons.menu_book,
                                isActive: controller.index == 3,
                              ),
                              Tabs(
                                'Watch',
                                Icons.watch_later_outlined,
                                isActive: controller.index == 4,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                            height: 400, //height of TabBarView
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border(
                                    top: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.grey, width: 0.5))),
                            child: TabBarView(
                                controller: controller,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: Text('Display Tab 1',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 22,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: Text('Display Tab 2',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 22,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: Text('Display Tab 3',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 22,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: Text('Display Tab 4',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 22,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: Text('Display Tab 5',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 22,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ]))
                      ]),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}

class Tabs extends StatelessWidget {
  final String header;
  final IconData iconName;
  final bool isActive;
  const Tabs(this.header, this.iconName, {required this.isActive, super.key});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Tab(
      icon: Container(
        width: 71,
        height: 71,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: isActive ? Colors.white : Colors.amber,
            shape: BoxShape.circle),
        child: IconButton(
            onPressed:null,//dont need this
            icon: Icon(
              iconName,
              size: 26,
              color: isActive ? Colors.amber : Colors.white,
            )),
      ),
      height: 97,
      text: header,
    );
  }
}
```